# Ordernar lista de listas

Tags: python-2.7

Eu tenho a seguinte lista de listas:

```
lista = [['a', '1'], ['c', '3'], ['b', '2']]
```

E eu quero ordenar esta lista de acordo com os números, ou seja, quero que ela fique assim:

```
listaOrdenada = [['a','1'], ['b','2'], ['c','3']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `sorted` e passar como segundo parâmetro a *key* que será feita a ordenação

```
listaOrdenada = sorted(lista, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: Obrigada, é isso mesmo! :)

Comment: E se eu tiver: `lista = [['ana','1'], ['anita','2'], ['rita','2']]` neste caso eu quero ordenar na mesma a lista de acordo com os numeros, mas como há 2 listas com o numero '2', nesse caso queria ordenar essas 2 listas por ordem alfabetica do nome, com um if possivelmente... sabe me dizer como fazer isso @jbueno ?

Comment: Sei sim @StinRose Abra uma nova pergunta, isso é um novo assunto

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

listaOrdenada =  [['a','1'], ['c','3'], ['b','2']]
print "List : ", sorted(listaOrdenada,key=lambda l:l[1], reverse=False)
```

Você pode usar lambda também.
:)

Comment: O AP quer organizar pelo segundo elemento, não pelo primeiro.

Comment: de fato, não percebi esse detalhe. editando aqui.

Comment: Agora tá certinho +1