# Ordenar listas de listas com dois critérios de ordenação

Tags: python-2.7

Se eu tiver uma lista de listas assim:

```
lista = [['ana','1'], ['joao', '3'], ['rita','2'], ['alice','2']]
```

Eu primeiro quero ordenar a lista de acordo com os numeros, para ficar assim:

```
lista = [['ana','1'], ['rita','2'], ['alice','2'], ['joao', '3']]
```

Que eu fiz com: `listaOrdenada = sorted(lista, key = lambda x: x[1])`

Mas como, neste caso, tenho duas listas com o numero '2', eu quero ordenar essas duas listas por ordem alfabética de acordo com o nome, como faço isso?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101159/ordernar-lista-de-listas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim

```
listaOrdenada = sorted(lista, key = lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

O lambda passado diz que o primeiro critério de ordenação é a coluna **1** e o segundo critério de ordenação é a coluna **0**.

Comment: acho que entendi.. então neste caso, ele primeiro vai ordenar consoante a segunda coluna da lista, e se eles forem iguais, vai ordenar consoante a primeira coluna da lista, certo?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer com `ordenar consoante`. Mas seu raciocínio está certo, o lambda passado diz que o primeiro critério de ordenação é a coluna **1** e o segundo critério de ordenação é a coluna **0**.

Comment: ok, mas o segundo critério de ordenação só vai acontecer se o primeiro critério for igual certo?

Comment: Exatamente. A ordenação só será definida pelo segundo critério quando não puder ser resolvida pelo primeiro.